# Is there anyway to restore snippets removed from chrome dev tool?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I was working some code in **snippets** in **chrome dev tools** and  I remove the file by mistake. I want to restore the file (*I spent alot of time optimizing my code*). Is there anyway, I could do that?
It would be great, if anyone can suggest a way to backup my working on chrome dev tools - snippets automatically, to avoid losing my working in future. Thank you and waiting for answers to my issue.

Comment: The only methods are: 1) another signed-in device that wasn't synced yet so turn off network connectivity before starting it and 2) restore the user profile from system backup if you're doing it like you should :-)